# CasperJS Variable as Capture Name

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I can't seem to figure out how to use casper.capture with a variable in the name of the screenshot

It works with regular strings as the name i.e:

```
casper.capture(picture.png)
```

however fails to work when I use something like this:

```
var VisitedDomain = 'http://google.com'
var ScreenshotName = 'SS' + '-' + 'VisitedDomain'

casper.capture(ScreenshotName + '.png');
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong since putting

```
console.log(ScreenshotName)
```

works fine

I know this is probably a really basic question but I've looked at a couple other examples of CasperJS scripts and the ones that have variables in the image name seem to work. If I do:

```
this.echo('Screenshot ' + ScreenshotName + ' taken!');
```

the printed value is correct.

NOTE:
I figured out the issue in my answer below but would still like to hear any creative methods of printing the valuable information in a URL to a screenshot name- perhaps replacing any values of "/" with "-"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out shortly after I wrote this question that Windows doesn't accept file names with these symbols:

```
A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
\ / : * ? " < > |
```

Because I was trying to use a URL in my file name this ended up preventing casper from being able to save the screenshot.